# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to insert a record that has decimal place, example: 7654.00 and the data type for this column is `numeric(10,12)` but I am getting arithmetic overflow error and I know I need to do a conversion first but not sure how..

The column I have the issue with is `TotalCost`.

Here is what I have:

```
string FullName = row.Cells[1].Text;
string TotalCost = row.Cells[6].ToString(); 

using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(myConnStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
         myCmd.Connection = myCon;
         myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         myCmd.CommandText = @"insert into myTable (FullName, TotalCost) 
                               values(@FullName, @TotalCost)";
         myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", FullName.ToString());

         myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalCost", TotalCost)

         myCon.Open();
         myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         myCon.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: If `TotalCost` is numeric, then it needs to be converted to decimal\double and then passed as `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@TotalCosts')`

Comment: AddWithValue has no way to know that you are passing a double if the second parameter is a string. Avoid it

Comment: `NUMERIC(10,12)` is impossible - that would mean a number with **10 digits** all together, **12 of which** to the right side of the decimal point....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddWithValue is a convenient shortcut to add a parameter, but has serious limitations as explained in these two blog posts

[Can We Stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
[How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

In your case, you are passing a string as second argument in the `AddWithValue` for the parameter `@TotalCost` and `AddWithValue`, diligently, pass a string to your database engine resulting in the mentioned error.

You should convert your string to a decimal value (It seems more appropriate to use a decimal for money values) and then add the parameter using a more explict declaration of your datatype

```
 string TotalCost = row.Cells[6].ToString(); 
 decimal cost;
 if(!decimal.TryParse(TotalCost, out cost))
     // Put here an error message for your user
     // "The value cannot be converted to a decimal value"
 else
 {
    using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(myConnStr))
    using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        myCmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myCmd.CommandText = @"insert into myTable (FullName, TotalCost ) 
                              values(@FullName, @TotalCost)";
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FullName;
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalCost", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = cost;
        myCon.Open();
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Of course you should adapt this code to the actual datatype of your `TotalCost` column on the datatable